# Trap the invalid Value for datetimepicker in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am displaying data in the textbox and datetimepicker from database. But some of the records are empty and it was invalid to display in the datetimepicker. I want to trap every empty date to set null in the datetimepicker. so far i have this code:

```
   if ((myReader["Born"].ToString()) == "" &&      (myReader["Died"].ToString()) != "" && (myReader["Interment"].ToString()) != "")
                {
                    textBox1.Text = (myReader["Surname"].ToString());
                    textBox2.Text = (myReader["FirstName"].ToString());
                    textBox3.Text = (myReader["MI"].ToString());
                    textBox4.Text = (myReader["Sex"].ToString());
                    dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                    dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
                    dateTimePicker2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader["Died"].ToString());
                    textBox7.Text = (myReader["Age"].ToString());
                    dateTimePicker3.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader["Interment"].ToString());
                    textBox9.Text = (myReader["Area"].ToString());
                }
                else if ((myReader["Died"].ToString()) == "" && (myReader["Born"].ToString()) != "" && (myReader["Interment"].ToString()) != "")
                {
                    textBox1.Text = (myReader["Surname"].ToString());
                    textBox2.Text = (myReader["FirstName"].ToString());
                    textBox3.Text = (myReader["MI"].ToString());
                    textBox4.Text = (myReader["Sex"].ToString());
                    dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader["Born"].ToString());
                    dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                    dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = " ";
                    textBox7.Text = (myReader["Age"].ToString());
                    dateTimePicker3.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader["Interment"].ToString());
                    textBox9.Text = (myReader["Area"].ToString());
                }
                else if ((myReader["Interment"].ToString()) == "" && (myReader["Born"].ToString()) != "" && (myReader["Died"].ToString()) == "")
                {
                    textBox1.Text = (myReader["Surname"].ToString());
                    textBox2.Text = (myReader["FirstName"].ToString());
                    textBox3.Text = (myReader["MI"].ToString());
                    textBox4.Text = (myReader["Sex"].ToString());
                    dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader["Born"].ToString());
                    dateTimePicker2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader["Died"].ToString());
                    textBox7.Text = (myReader["Age"].ToString());
                    dateTimePicker3.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                    dateTimePicker3.CustomFormat = " ";
                    textBox9.Text = (myReader["Area"].ToString());
                }
```

Comment: The DTP doesnt accept null/empty dates

Comment: Are they stored as dates or strings in the database?

Comment: strings @Peter4499

Comment: Since you can't set the DateTimePicker to null, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @KSib this code works,i can set the datetimepicker to null but not complete and too long. I want to minimize it and completely trap the invalid.

Comment: So if you do dateTimePicker2.Value = null; That compiles and runs? Ignoring all the rest of the code? We are talking about System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker, right?

Answer (score 0):

"I want to trap every empty date to set null in the datetimepicker. so far i have this code" - the below code does the same thing as the original code, but should handle additional cases of invalid dates.

"this code works,i can set the datetimepicker to null but not complete and too long. I want to minimize it and completely trap the invalid."
The original code is not setting it to null, the below code does the same thing.

"I want to minimize it and completely trap the invalid" - that is what the below code is and does.

```
textBox1.Text = myReader["Surname"].ToString();
textBox2.Text = myReader["FirstName"].ToString();
textBox3.Text = myReader["MI"].ToString();
textBox4.Text = myReader["Sex"].ToString();
textBox7.Text = myReader["Age"].ToString();
textBox9.Text = myReader["Area"].ToString();
trySetDateTimePickerValue(myReader["Born"], dateTimePicker1);
trySetDateTimePickerValue(myReader["Died"], dateTimePicker2);
trySetDateTimePickerValue(myReader["Interment"], dateTimePicker3);

// ...

public void trySetDateTimePickerValue(DateTimePicker dateTimePicker, SomeTypeOfReader reader)
{
    if (reader != null)
    {
        string cleanDate = reader.ToString().Trim(); 
        if (cleanDate.Length > 0) // maybe this trim/test is overkill, maybe the TryParse below is sufficient
        {
            DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(cleanDate, out parsedDate)
            {
                dateTimePicker.Value = parsedDate;
                return; // success - exit method
            }
        }
    }

    // no valid date in string:

    // this is the default value if no value is set according to MSDN
    dateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now;

    // show nothing in the picker (not sure if this is good solution, this is what the original code does)
    dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = " ";

}
```

The code maintains the original, bad object names (textBox1, textBox2,...)

Also note that the code is culturally sensitive, the date time parsing may behave differently in different locales (just like the original code). Supply additional arguments to the date time parsing methods to specify the culture if required.

Answer (score -1):

WOuld strongly recommend refactoring the code, you have nearly identical blocks of code repeating three times and makes the code extreamly difficult to read. Break out the identical parts and put only the differing parts in if clauses.

As to solving the actual issue, something like this should work:

```
setDateTimerPickerValueIfExists(dateTimePicker1, myReader["Born"]);
setDateTimerPickerValueIfExists(dateTimePicker2, myReader["Died"]);

//..

private void setDateTimerPickerValueIfExists(DateTimePicker dateTimePicker, xxxxxxxReader reader) {
    if (reader != null) {
        dateTimePicker.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new here but why the downvote? o_O If the answer is bad or incorrect, would be nice to know why.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I don't see where this sets the DateTimePicker to null. I'm still trying to figure out how OP is supposedly setting it to null since that shouldn't be possible, but we'll see.

Comment: After reading the question and your discussion 20 more times I think the problem is he wants to catch more cases and have less bulky code. I think by "set to null" he means keeping & hiding its default value (setting " " as custom format) like he does in the original code. I submitted a new answer based on this.